# stroftime code not displaying date on new web server

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, strtotime

I have created a blog and have it set so that on each blog post the date that the post was made is displayed, I have always done it using stroftime() and getting the recorded date from MySQL Database where the posts are being stored.

This has always worked but I just recently switched to a new web host and when I try to use the original code:

```
<?php $date = strtotime($post['post_date']);
        echo date('F jS, Y', $date); ?>
```

I get an error stating:

```
Warning: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.
```

I'm just not understanding where they want me to replace with date_default_timezone_set().

Answer (score 1):

Php expects the default timezone to be set by application not by system. Therefore you have to invoke date_default_timezone_set sonewhere at the beginning of your script or part of initialization . Then you can safely invoke strtotime.

```
 date_default_timezone_set('UTC')
 ...
 strtotime (...)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can config it in php.ini file such as:

```
date.timezone = "US/Central" // US/Central is your default timezone
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to call the function  [date_default_timezone_set($timezone)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) somewhere in your code before you call any datetime functions.  You should always check out the php documentation pages for things like this.

You need to call this in your code with the correct timezone for where you are and then call your code.  YOu will find a list of timezones on the php documentation [website here](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

eg for all my code I do.

```
 date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Dublin');

 strtotime ('yesterday 12:30 pm');
```

This only needs to be done once in your code, so you can put it in a config file or something that is loaded by all your scripts.